# Am using drf-spectacular for my Django rest api documentation am getting below error when i am trying to over SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS in setting.py

Tags: python, django, swagger

Settings are configurable in settings.py in the scope SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS. You can override any setting, otherwise the defaults below are used.
for ref:  https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

[[image: 'OAUTH2_SCOPES': None, NameError: name 'Dict' is not defined1]

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be a comment, could you please include your code where you are overriding settings? But I'd guess you tried to add a type to your setting (Dict) without importing Dict. I don't believe you need the type there if you have it.

So you can either take out the types and just have

```
`SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = { ... }`
```

or import the types you are using `from typing import Dict, Any`

Comment: for ref: https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: Does this not answer your question? If not please include your code

Comment: no worries glad you have a solution! Please close your question and mark the answer as accepted.